# Change in focus behavior during TableView selection between JavaFX 2 and 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an application that manages a list of documents. One view of the documents in maintained in a TableView showing author, title, etc. Other views have things like publisher, number of pages, notes, abstract, and so on depending on the type of document selected. The user selects the active document by clicking a new row in the TableView.

As the users edit the document information in the various views, the changes are committed to a database as the individual controls lose focus. This worked fine until trying to switch from Java 7/JavaFX 2 to 8.

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to illustrate the problem.

```
package focusproblem;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import static javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FocusProblem extends Application {

    private TextArea notesArea;
    private TableView docTable;

    private ObservableList<Doc> initDocs() {
        ObservableList<Doc> docList = observableArrayList();
        docList.add(new Doc("Harper Lee", "To Kill a Mockbird",
                "Some notes on mockingbirds"));
        docList.add(new Doc("John Steinbeck", "Of Mice and Men",
                "Some notes about mice"));
        docList.add(new Doc("Lewis Carroll", "Jabberwock",
                "Some notes about jabberwocks"));
        return docList;
    }

    private Parent initGui(ObservableList<Doc> d) {
        notesArea = new TextArea();
        notesArea.setId("notesArea");
        notesArea.setPromptText("Add notes here");
        notesArea.focusedProperty().addListener(new FocusPropertyChangeListener());

        TableColumn<Doc, String> authorCol = new TableColumn<>("Author");
        authorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doc, String>("author"));
        authorCol.setMinWidth(100.0d);
        TableColumn<Doc, String> titleCol = new TableColumn<>("Title");
        titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doc, String>("title"));
        titleCol.setMinWidth(250.0d);

        docTable = new TableView<>(d);
        docTable.setPrefHeight(200.0d);
        docTable.getColumns().addAll(authorCol, titleCol);
        docTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new SelectionChangeListener());
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(docTable, notesArea);
        return vb;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Focus Problem");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(initGui(initDocs())));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class SelectionChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Doc> {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Doc> observable, Doc oldDoc, Doc newDoc) {
            System.out.println("Changing selected row");
            if (oldDoc != null) {
                notesArea.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldDoc.notesProperty());
            }
            if (newDoc != null) {
                notesArea.setText(newDoc.getNotes());
                newDoc.notesProperty().bindBidirectional(notesArea.textProperty());
            }
        }
    }

    public class FocusPropertyChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                Boolean oldb, Boolean newb) {
            if (ov instanceof ReadOnlyBooleanProperty) {
                Object obj = ((ReadOnlyBooleanProperty) ov).getBean();
                if (obj instanceof TextArea) {
                    TextArea ta = (TextArea) obj;
                    if (ta.isVisible() && !ta.isDisabled()) {
                        boolean b = (newb != null && newb == true);
                        if (b) {
                            System.out.println(ta.getId() + " gained focus");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(ta.getId() + " lost focus");
                            Doc d = (Doc) docTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                            if (d != null) {
                                System.out.println("  Need to update db entry for '"
                                        + d.getTitle() + "' with '" + ta.getText() + "'");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Doc {

        private final SimpleStringProperty author;
        private final SimpleStringProperty title;
        private final SimpleStringProperty notes;

        public Doc(String author, String title, String notes) {
            this.author = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "author", author);
            this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "title", title);
            this.notes = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "notes", notes);
        }

        public void setAuthor(String value) {
            author.set(value);
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            System.out.println("Trying to get author");
            return author.get();
        }

        public StringProperty authorProperty() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setTitle(String value) {
            title.set(value);
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title.get();
        }

        public StringProperty titleProperty() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setNotes(String value) {
            notes.set(value);
        }

        public String getNotes() {
            return notes.get();
        }

        public StringProperty notesProperty() {
            return notes;
        }
    }
}
```

When run after compiling with either version of Java, the program looks something like this (on Windows):

[image: An image of the running program.]

To demonstrate the problem, perform these steps:

- Select "Of Mice and Men"
- Select the TextArea for notes (the area below the TableView)
- Change the notes text to "Some **lengthy** notes
  about mice"
- In the TableView, select the row for "Jabberwock"

When the program is compiled with Java 7, the console output is:

```
Changing selected row
notesArea gained focus
notesArea lost focus
  Need to update db entry for 'Of Mice and Men' with 'Some lengthy notes about mice'
Changing selected row
```

as expected. The database is updated with the correct information.

When the program is compiled with Java 8, the console output is:

```
Changing selected row
notesArea gained focus
Changing selected row
notesArea lost focus
  Need to update db entry for 'Jabberwock' with 'Some notes about jabberwocks'
```

In this output, the wrong document is updated and the real changes are not written to the database. It appears that the TableView gains focus before the TextArea loses it.

Is this a bug or expected behavior now with Java 8? Any known workarounds? Or am I just a bonehead for doing it this way?

Comment: in 8u60b5, the output is as you described, the note that is changed seems to be the correct one, though: selecting Steinbeck again shows the changed note in the textarea

Comment: ahh... now I see the problem - misunderstood it ;-) Well, I think your approach isn't correct - you can't rely on any sequence of notification: there is no specification (that I know of) that guarantees that focus-lost precedes any change to table selection. If that had been the case in fx2, it was just accidental. IThe form needs some reference to the doc it is editing (vs. assuming that it is the currently selectedItem on focuslost)

Comment: @kleopatra - Thanks for the comment. Did not understand that you couldn't rely on particular sequence of events. Will try to remedy my ignorance and look for a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I can reproduce this behavior, but I would neither call this a bug nor try to fiddle with the focus system. Instead why don't you rewrite your `SelectionChangeListener` - there is no need to watch the focus of the `TextArea`:

```
public class SelectionChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Doc> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Doc> observable, Doc oldDoc, Doc newDoc) {
        System.out.println("Changing selected row");
        if (oldDoc != null) {
            System.out.println("  Need to update db entry for '"
                    + oldDoc.getTitle() + "' with '" + oldDoc.getNotes() + "'");
            notesArea.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldDoc.notesProperty());
        }
        if (newDoc != null) {
            notesArea.setText(newDoc.getNotes());
            newDoc.notesProperty().bindBidirectional(notesArea.textProperty());
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output for your testcase:

```
Changing selected row
notesArea gained focus
Changing selected row
  Need to update db entry for 'Of Mice and Men' with 'Some lengthy notes about mice'
notesArea lost focus
```

Comment: in fact, there _is_ a need to watch for focusLost: afaiu the OP, the requirement is to commit on ... well ... focusLost of each of several controls that can edit a property. So we need a listener to the focusLost, but it must not rely on the selectedItem being the one it is currently bound to.

Comment: @kleopatra I disagree on that one. Currently neither of the two approaches correctly identifies a commit event. This can be done inside the `Doc` class (check whether the value changed, etc.).

Comment: don't see any ground for disagreement - committing on focusLost can be a requirement and requirements rule ;-)

Comment: @eckig - Thanks for the reply. The biggest problem with updating in the ChangeListener on the TableView is that a user can make a change, click the close decoration, and lose the change. That is not a problem when monitoring loss of focus.

Comment: @clartaq As I said in the comments: Currently you do not have any reliable way of detecting user input changes. You could e.g. add a dirty flag to your data class that gets toggled on the first change to the internal `textProperty` so you know exactly what has changed and needs to be updated. The current approach is no more than a best guess..

Comment: @eckig - took your advice and added ChangeListeners on the fields of the document model to implement a dirty flag. Now, monitoring the change in row selection triggers the check for a need to update the database. Also overrode the stop() method of main class to catch the case where the program is closed without changing rows in the table.